How do I format pseudo-bibliographic paragraphs (not real biblatex citations) in Pandoc markdown for PDF & EPUB outputs?
Say in the middle of the text I want to create pseudo-bibliographic entries that are just normal paragraphs but formatted like a bibliography. In LibreOffice, this is trivial: I just change the indentation of the paragraph.
Consider the following mock-up using a code block:
Oblique delenit salutatus eos id, an legimus maiorum sed, sea omittantur 
necessitatibus et. See the following: 

Auditore, Ezio. (1635). Mediocrem rationibus neglegentur no sed. 
     Florence, Italy: Sea erant ceteros imperdiet ex.

Mea cu habeo mentitum oporteat, pro ut commodo eloquentiam instructior.
Other paragraph text etc. etc. 


See also this mock-up on LibreOffice:

So far this is a technique in Pandoc I haven't learned yet. I'll be using this to export to PDF and EPUB, if that helps.
I've searched online and checked the manual but haven't found what I want. HTML tags in markdown seems to work for formatting on EPUB, but it didn't work for PDFs. I need a solution that exports to both.

For a PDF you can use \hangindent but this will work only for latex/pdf output and ignored in other formats. AFAIK there is no markdown way to do the French indentation, except maybe to use both the latex command plus the HTML tags. But in the best case will work only for PDF and HTML outputs.

I can try using a combination of \hangindent and HTML I think.
